# Incrementing iterator that is used as first and last of std::multimap erase range

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, stdmap

While running an example that shows how to erase a range from std::map/multimap I have noticed strange behaviour in the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, std::string> myMap;

    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three1"));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three2"));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three3"));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(45, "fourty five"));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(-1, "minus one"));

    std::multimap<int, std::string>::iterator iter = myMap.find(3);
    if (iter != myMap.end()) {
        myMap.erase(iter, iter++); //segmentation fault(!)
    }

    for (auto element : myMap) {
        std::cout << element.first << " -> " << element.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which I build with command `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp` (I use g++ 5.2.1).

Why  post-incrementation of my iterator causes a Segmentation fault?
I would rather say that this should create 2 copies of this iterator, pass them into the erase method, "erase nothing" just as would code `myMap.erase(iter, iter);` and then increment the `iter`.

What logic stands behind this segfault?

Is this an invalid use of `iter` iterator? If so - why?

BTW.
It compiles when I use pre-incrementation `myMap.erase(iter, ++iter)` and here it "erase nothing" as I mentioned above.

Comment: If you just want to erase a single element, `iter = erase(iter);` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks JonathanPotter but that's not it. I just wasn't aware that order of evaluation of the arguments to a function call is not defined. Seems like Christophe answered my question below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the arguments to a function call is not defined.  So when you write:

```
   myMap.erase(iter, iter++); //segmentation fault(!)
```

the compiler is free to evaluate the second argument first, or not. As you use the same iterator, but have a side effect, you get Undefined Behaviour (*refer to C++ standard, section 1.9/15*).

For example, if the compiler evaluates first the second argument `iter++`, the incremented iterator would be used as the first argument, while second argument is not incremented `iter`. As a consequence: the range passed to erase() would be `[std::next(iter), iter)`- the function might attempt to erase elements that are out of range (i.e. UB).

As suggested by David in the comments, you can solve the issue with `iter = myMap.erase(iter)` (or using a range without side effects).

Comment: Additionally, you can correct the problem by doing: `iter = myMap.erase(iter);`

Comment: What's "undetermined"? It's UB, because one of the possible executions of the abstract machine contains an undefined operation.

Comment: @T.C. the evaluation of the argumens being indeterminately sequenced, I used the term indeterminate abusively. It's definitively undefined behaviour.   I'll edit

Comment: Still not quite right. 1.9/15 doesn't apply - these are overloaded operators and so function calls, and are indeterminately sequenced rather than unsequenced. The problem is that one of the possible executions would pass an invalid range (the equivalent of `[std::next(iter), iter)`) to `erase` (which is undefined), so the entire program's behavior is also undefined (see 1.9/5).

Comment: @T.C. Thank you for your comment. Now I think I understand, but let me rephrase- one of the possible executions is that second argument evaluates first (being passed to erase method as iter) and then comes incrementation followed by evaluation of first argument (as incremented iter) - this gives us what you wrote above: `[std::next(iter), iter)`.

Comment: @T.C. Doesn't 1.9/15 explicitely mention operands of operators and even provides an example ub with side effects in a function call ?

Comment: You mean the `f(i = -1, f = -1)`? That's UB by itself but not relevant here. `iter++` is a function call itself, because a `multimap`'s iterator can't possibly be a built-in type. Hence it's indeterminately sequenced, rather than unsequenced.

Comment: The difference is that `int i = 0; void f(int, int); f(i, i++);` is UB in all cases regardless of `f`, but `erase(iter, iter++)` is UB only because `erase` requires a valid range.